# Отправка сообщений из другого потока aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот, который запускает новый поток после /start. Но надо сделать так чтоб в отдельном потоке бот прислала сообщнеие, подскажите как это сделать.

```
import threading
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot_token = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=second)
    thread.start()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Привет!")


def second():
    # выполнение кода
    bot.send_message(chat_id=1234567890, text="Привет еще раз!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо многопоточности вы должны использовать асинхронность, код должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.utils import executor
import asyncio

bot_token = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage, loop=loop)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    loop.create_task(second())
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Привет!")


async def second():
    # выполнение кода
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=1234567890, text="Привет еще раз!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot_token = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    await bot.send_message(1234567890, "Привет еще раз!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]